# Steping back from applied patch

Tags: deployment, patch

When creating a patch with the "patch" tool or with the built in "patch"-functionality in svn and then applying it to a source tree, is there any way to easily *step* back from the applied patch to the previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the patch again in reverse (for example patch -R switch).

Answer (score 1):

svn revert? You can revert to the previous revision (before the patch was applied).